# Is there a way to use function argument as a label in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quick question: if I want to run a function, such as `plt.diff(dataset1)`, and in the output graph, I want the function to use the name "dataset1" as the y-axis label, how can this be done?

```
plt.diff <- function(x){ 
  x$kind <- as.factor(x$kind)
    ggplot(x,aes(x=as.factor(nodes), fill= age)) + labs(title = 'Difference plot',
                x = 'points', y = deparse(substitute(x)) ) + geom_text(
                aes(label = nodes, y = diff)) +
                geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(y = diff)) + 
                geom_bar(stat="identity", aes( y = (diff*(-1)))) + 
                coord_flip()}
```

As you can see, I've already tried `deparse(substitute(x))` and it doesn't work. This is the output for the y-axis currently:
`structure(list(nodes= structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would extract the name of the object passed to the function early on via `deparse(substitute(x))`, and then pass this to 
ggplot. This ensures that the name of the object is based on the function argument passed to plt.diff and not
to ggplot within plt.diff.

Using a toy data set:

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(nodes = 1:10, kind = 1:10, age = rpois(10, 20), diff = rpois(10,5))

library(ggplot2)

plt.diff <- function(x){
  x_name <- deparse(substitute(x))  
  x$kind <- as.factor(x$kind)
  ggplot(x, aes(x = as.factor(nodes), fill = age)) + 
    labs(title = 'Difference plot', x = 'points', y = x_name) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = nodes, y = diff)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(y = diff)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes( y = (diff*(-1)))) + 
    coord_flip()}

plt.diff(dataset1)
```

[image: ggplot2 bar chart]

Comment: Thank you! Not sure if I should make a new question for this, but I realized that if I want to run this function on a list using `lapply`, the name of each member of the list is not used as the axis name, rather `X[I]` is used, where i is the index in the list. I'll make a new question if it is warranted

Comment: @JerryW. Yes, I would recommend a new question since it's a slightly different problem. The question would also likely pick up more interest if you also provide a data set via dput as well as expected output.